# C++11 inline lambda functions without template

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I want to pass lambda function as callback to another function:

```
void test(const std::function<void()> fn){
    fn();
}
```

It works, all ok. But. It does not inline it, no matter how high compiler optimization level I use: 
[proof](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22:3,%22filterAsm%22%3a%7B%22labels%22%3atrue,%22directives%22%3atrue,%22commentOnly%22%3atrue,%22colouriseAsm%22%3atrue%7D,%22compilers%22%3a%5B%7B%22source%22%3a%22#include%20%3Ciostream%3E%5Cn#include%20%3Cfunctional%3E%5Cn%5Cnusing%20namespace%20std;%5Cn%5Cnint%20h;%5Cnvoid%20test%28const%20std%3a%3afunction%3Cvoid%28%29%3E%20fn%29%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20fn%28%29;%5Cn%7D%5Cnint%20main%28%29%20%7B%5Cn%5Cn%20%20%20%20test%28%5B%5D%20%28%29%20%7B%20h=3;%7D%29;%5Cn%20%20%20%20return%200;%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22,%22compiler%22%3a%22/usr/bin/g++-4.8%22,%22options%22%3a%22-O4%20-std=c++11%22%7D%5D%7D)

And when I play a while, I found, that with template -it becomes inlined:

```
template<typename T>     
void test2(T fn){
     fn();
}
```

[proof_2](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22:3,%22filterAsm%22%3a%7B%22labels%22%3atrue,%22directives%22%3atrue,%22commentOnly%22%3atrue,%22colouriseAsm%22%3atrue%7D,%22compilers%22%3a%5B%7B%22source%22%3a%22#include%20%3Ciostream%3E%5Cn#include%20%3Cfunctional%3E%5Cn%5Cnusing%20namespace%20std;%5Cn%5Cnint%20h;%5Cntemplate%3Ctypename%20T%3E%20%20%20%20%20%5Cn%20%20void%20test2%28T%20fn%29%7B%5Cn%20%20fn%28%29;%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnint%20main%28%29%20%7B%5Cn%5Cn%20%20%20%20test2%28%5B%5D%20%28%29%20%7B%20h=3;%7D%29;%5Cn%20%20%20%20return%200;%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22,%22compiler%22%3a%22/usr/bin/g++-4.8%22,%22options%22%3a%22-O4%20-std=c++11%22%7D%5D%7D)

So... Is there any way to make it inlined without templates? And why it becomes inlined with template declaration? Only function type is passing as template argument, not the function itself.

Comment: `std::function` is a type erasure class (that will most likely invoke fn indirectly via a function pointer). capturing a lambda via `std::function` almost certainly kills your opportunities to inline it.

Comment: @Alex but doesn't "typename T" deducts to the same std::function ?

Comment: @tower120 No, the type of a lambda expression is not `std::function`. It's *"unnamed, unique, non-union class type, called closure type"*. See ISO C++ §5.1.2/3.

Comment: @tower120: `typename T` is deducting the actual type of the lambda. `std::function<void()>` is capturing any function that is callable without arguments but hiding the actual type of fn. and in order to forget the actual type of fn you either need a vtable or a function pointer.

Comment: @Alex And what is "actual type of the lambda"? :)

Comment: @tower120 As jrok mentioned, it is unnamed. There is no way to explicitly write down the type of a lambda, but it is guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: @tower120 see the answer of angew. the type is compiler generated and unique. I think (without research), that the standard doesn't allow you to know the type. only deduce it via template arguemnts.

Comment: @Alex You can use `decltype` or template argument deduction to get hold of the type, or `auto` to use it indirectly. I don't think there's any other way.

Comment: @Angew Ah I totally forgot about them. However both are not allowed in Argument Lists of functions?

Comment: @Alex You certainly can't use `auto` for a parameter type, but [`decltype` is just fine](http://ideone.com/LMwcrJ). Of course, it means you can only pass in that particular lambda - not really usable in practice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer: no, you can't make this work without templates (in the general case). The reason is that each lambda expression in your source code generates a *unique type* for that lambda closure. [Proof](http://ideone.com/ulrFZX):

```
auto f1 = [] { return 1; };
auto f2 = [] { return 1; };
static_assert(!std::is_same<decltype(f1), decltype(f2)>::value, "He's wrong");
```

Therefore, to accept an arbitrary closure, you either have to use a template, or a type-erasure wrapper (such as `std::function`). Of course, type erasure relies on runtime polymorphism, so it doesn't lend itself to inlining.

The only way you could potentially make this work is with a stateless lambda (no capture), which has an implicit conversion to a pointer to function. Have your algorithm take the parameter as such a pointer to function, and hope the optimiser sees deep enough to inline the call. In other words, change the function to this:

```
void test(void (*fn)()) {
    fn();
}
```

Comment: Isn't my example lambda stateless? It does not capture anything.

Comment: @tower120 Yes it is. So if you change the function signature to take a pointer to function instead of a `std::function`, it should work. Note: answer edited

Comment: @tower120 yes it's stateless, so try if your compiler inlines the call with `void test3(void (*fn)()){ fn(); }`

Comment: It works in simple cases, but in more real - no http://tinyurl.com/qzeoher. You may add this to your answer.